# Can an opponent deploy units behind my base, if I build it beside the natural border of my land?

Tags: star-wars-commander

In Star Wars Commander you are given a tract of virtual land where you can build your base.  I have yet to engage a multiplayer opponent and, from what the game states, I will not be attacked until I first attack another player.

Since I am about to start attacking opponents, I want to be sure that I have an optimal base layout.  My question is, can I use a corner of my build-grid as a natural barrier, or will the game allow an attacking opponent the ability to deploy opponents a square or two from behind the barrier of where I am allowed to build?

Currently I can build 60 wall units and that isn't enough to protect all of my buildings.  However, if I can use an edge of my space to my advantage, I think I can wall-in all of my buildings and protect myself from a rebel assault.

Comment: What I do know is that players can deploy units inside your base if there is sufficient space...the little grey boxes that display 1 point out of each of your buildings edges show where the enemy cannot place units. This is very helpful when attacking. Not sure about outside the boundary, but I would assume yes, they can.

Comment: I don't *think* you are right.  In one of the AI battles, I tried to deploy a few troopers at the edge of the map.  It wouldn't let me.  The map also drew a greyish square around the map which outlined the boundary, just as it outlines boudaries of enemy buildings.

Comment: Right, could go either way. Could also change in an update o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an opponent can deploy from behind your buildings if they are placed on the edge of a map.

On the official (and new) forum, a user asked why so many high-level players were building their bases in corners.  This was the response:

> You can place troops in the corner. There is a small sliver of land
>   that runs around the whole map. The reason a lot of people do this is
>   because when you drop troops there, they have no choice but to be
>   bunched together and the mortars and rockets destroy everything quite
>   easily.

([Source](https://www.playdomforums.com/showthread.php?139023-Base-placement&s=8abf911eb24f325339f07ea4fb53f107&p=2319587#post2319587))

Answer (score 1):

Not only that but if your shield goes over that sliver the troops will land inside your shield.

As for the number of walls, they don't need to enclose all of your buildings. They should be used in a way that slows down the progress of the attacker and separates small units from larger ones (the little guys walk and the big guys have to stop to take the walls our).